# How to deal with this data structure in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck on a problem and I've no idea in which direction should I go. There is a array of objects and I want to check if there was previously exact type, if so then copy the properites and add new one without a type property, if not push the object to the array.

### Example 1:

**Expected input:**

```js
const arr = [
    {type: 1, amount: 100},
    {type: 2, amount: 200},
    {type: 3, amount: 300},
]

const obj = {type: 1, name: 'PLN'}
```

**Expected output:**

```js
arr = [
    {type: 1, amount: 100, name: 'PLN'},
    {type: 2, amount: 200},
    {type: 3, amount: 300},
]
```

### Example 2:

**Expected input:**

```js
const arr = [
    {type: 1, amount: 100},
    {type: 2, amount: 200},
    {type: 3, amount: 300},
]

const obj = {type: 4, amount: 400}
```

**Expected output:**

```js
arr = [
    {type: 1, amount: 100},
    {type: 2, amount: 200},
    {type: 3, amount: 300},
    {type: 4, amount: 400},
]
```

If something is unclear please let me know :)

Comment: Neither of your examples actually contain any example code. Only inputs and outputs. Please edit this and add [mcve]s

Comment: @evolutionxbox sure